# SharePoint 2013 New List Redirect

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-library

I want to redirect to another url (i.e. google) after a list item is saved, seems simple, but can't figure it out. What would code look like, here is my save code in newform:

```
<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton1"/>
</td>
```

Is it possible to create a redirect rule?

Comment: code:<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
       <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton1"/>
      
      </td>

Answer (score 1):

Here was my no code solution that may help you.  I set the link to the new form to have a source defined.  Then when the OK button is pressed, they are returned to the "source" URL.

Example:`http://<site>/Announcements/Forms/NewItem.aspx?Source=http://<site>/default.aspx`

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexma/archive/2006/06/17/635346.aspx%E2%80%8B) is where I found the idea on MSDN 2 years ago